# Can you explain this JavaScript syntax (variable extrapolation)?

Tags: javascript

I just saw something I have never seen before and cannot seem to find an explanation of what it really is... not in the ES5.1 standard and ES6 draft, nor in the [Mozilla ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla) support.

Please explain technically what is happening (anonymous object, anonymous block?) and provide some reference to a section in the ES standard or some other resource that explains this.

The context is a firefox extension.

```
const // var also works here it seems
{
      classes    : Cc
    , interfaces : Ci
    , utils      : Cu

} = Components
```

It creates variables Cc, Ci, Cu on the current scope. It's kind of counter intuitive since this looks like an anonymous object, but then one would expect property names on the left and values on the right...

Source of the construct in question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/JavaScript_Object_Management

update: Thanks to Leo I found the right word for it (destructuring). I found [this blog](http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/50/) explains it quite nicely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is ES6 [**Destructuring**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). More specifically [**Object Destructuring**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

`Components` should be something like this:

```
{classes: 'asdf', interfaces: 'qwer', utils: `zxcv`}
```

Then you get three constants (defined with [**`const`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), which is readonly after assignment):

```
Cc // 'asdf'
Ci // 'qwer'
Cu // 'zxcv'
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I still find it counter intuitive to assign from left to right but then I'm not obliged to use it either...

Comment: @nus Yep, I don't like the syntax either, but it's quite convenient.

Comment: It drew my attention because I like concise code, but if every person who reads my code afterwards is going to scratch their heads for 5 mins, it's of questionable use. I'd probably comment it with: 'destructuring'.

Comment: @nus eh, it's es6. It won't be usable in production environments for a decade anyway.

Comment: @slicedtoad In browser, yes. In serverside, e.g. NodeJS, it would be very soon :)

Comment: @slicedtoad it seems to work in firefox extensions as well. MDN lists a plethora of ES6 features they already support. On top of that, by specifying the javascript version in script tags it can be used in firefox by web pages as well.

Comment: @nus I think syntax similar to this is quite common in functional programming languages (which JavaScript likes to pretend to be). In FP, it's common for functions to return tuples that can be decomposed into their parts like this. I wouldn't be surprised if we start seeing something like this in other major languages in the near futre.

Comment: @ JLRishe The counter intuitive thing is not getting compound values. It's that you get `{ incomingValue : variableName }` Note that `incomingValue :` eg. the LEFT side is optional. I'm not so sure other programming languages do that alot, then I'm not a fan of functional languages, so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As [the Mozilla documentation states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.classes):

> It's a common practice to abbreviate `Components.classes` and
>   `Components.interfaces` by storing a reference to the object as a
>   constant:
>
> `const Cc = Components.classes, Ci = Components.interfaces;`
>
> `var os = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
>            .getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);`

What you're seeing here is this common practice compacted further with ES6 object destructuring.